# Comparing two arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've got two arrays in Javascript which currently look like this, but are updated by HTTP requests (node):

```
var x = [[292,"2349","902103","9"],[3289,"93829","092","920238"]]
var y = [[292,"2349","902103","9"],[322,"93829","092","920238"],[924,"9320","8932","4329"]]
```

I'm looking to compare these arrays, so that, if there is an array inside y that is not in x, it will be saved to a new array - `z`. Note that sometimes the order of arrays inside the arrays will change, but I would not like this to affect the result.

If there is an array inside x that is not in y, however, is should not be saved to `z`.

I read [JavaScript array difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/javascript-array-difference) and have been able to replicate this, but if the `x` array is not shown in `y`, it is printed to `z`. I am wondering if it is possible for this not to be stored, only the different items in `y`?

Comment: Will the inner arrays always contain strings & numbers ?

Comment: They will always be in this format (always in the same order): [int,"str","str","str"].

Comment: so the ints need to be different? is that enough ?

Comment: If the array in `y` is not in `x` save array to `z`?

Comment: @JordanHendrix Anything in the array being different should save this array to the new array. Some arrays often have the same initial integer.

Comment: @guest271314 Yes, correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate. The [How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript) question asks about comparing arrays which contains only primitives, like numbers or strings, whereas this question asks about comparing arrays which contain other arrays.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a higher-order function that accepts an array (which changes with each iteration of `y`) and returns a new function that operates on each element (nested array) in `some`. It returns `true` if the arrays contain the same elements regardless of order.

```
function matches(outer) {
  return function (el) {
    if (outer.length !== el.length) return false;
    return el.every(function (x) {
      return outer.indexOf(x) > -1;
    });
  }
}
```

Iterate over `y` and return a list of arrays that aren't in `x`.

```
function finder(x, y) {
  return y.filter(function (el) {
    return !x.some(matches(el));
  });
}

finder(x, y);
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2hLxpde0/3/)

Comment: Is the `.reduce` in `finder` any different from a `.filter`?

Comment: Not really in this case. I added an edit to my answer.

Comment: This might not affect the OP's use case, but your `matches` function will return true for two subarrays that have items in different order: `matches([1, '2', '3'])(['3', 1, '2']) === true`.  It will also return true if the first array has extra items in it: `matches([1, 4,  '2', '3', 5, '6'])(['3', 1, '2']) === true`.

Comment: Not worried about the first point as the OP clarified that in his comments, but you're right about your second point and I've updated my code to reflect that, cheers @NoahFreitas.

Comment: You can also use [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) instead of `.indexOf()` to determine whether an array contains specific element.

Comment: @Andy This appears to print out "true", rather than the concerned arrays. Could you suggest a way of modifying it to give the concerned arrays?

Comment: @GregW, no it doesn't. Look at the demo - it returns an array of results.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this function `arrayDiff`.

It takes two arrays (A and B) and returns an array of all elements that are in the first array and not in the second (A \ B), with any duplicates removed.  Two array elements are equal if their JSON serialization is the same.

```
var x = [[292,"2349","902103","9"],[3289,"93829","092","920238"]];
var y = [[292,"2349","902103","9"],[322,"93829","092","920238"],[924,"9320","8932","4329"]];

var z = arrayDiff(y, x);

// z is [[322,"93829","092","920238"],[924,"9320","8932","4329"]]

// arrayDiff :: [a], [a] -> [a]
function arrayDiff(a1, a2) {
    let a1Set = toStringSet(a1),
        a2Set = toStringSet(a2);

    return Array.from(a1Set)
                .filter(jsonStr => !a2Set.has(jsonStr))
                .map(JSON.parse);

    // toStringSet :: [a] -> Set<String>
    function toStringSet(arr) {
        return new Set(arr.map(JSON.stringify));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work even if the order in the inner arrays is different.
I'm assuming you will have only numbers and strings in there and you don't expect a strict comparison between them.

```
var x = [[292,"2349","902103","9"],[3289,"93829","092","920238"]];
var y = [[292,"2349","902103","9"],[322,"93829","092","920238"],[924,"9320","8932","4329"]];

// this will do y \ x
var z = arrDiff(y, x);
console.log(z);


function arrDiff(arr1, arr2) {
  var rez = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    if ( ! contains(arr2, arr1[i])) {
      rez.push(arr1[i]);
    }
  }

  return rez;
}

function contains(arr, x) {
  x = x.slice().sort().toString();
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    // compare current item with the one we are searching for        
    if (x === arr[i].slice().sort().toString()) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function getArraysDiff(arr1, arr2) {
   var x = arr1.map(function(a) { return a.join("") });
   var y = arr2.map(function(a) { return a.join("") });
   var z = [];

   for ( var i = 0, l = arr1.length; i < l; i++ ) {
      if ( y.indexOf(x[i]) == -1 ) {
        z.push(arr1[i])
      }
   }

   return z;
}
```

Or this:

```
x.filter((function(y) {
    return function(x) {
        return y.indexOf(x.join("")) > -1;
    }
}( y.map(function(y) { return y.join("") }) )))
```

Comment: What if the sort order of internal arrays cannot be guaranteed to be same on both sides?

Comment: @GregW Can you clarify whether the order is guaranteed?

Comment: @fahadash I guess he could do a .sort() before the join

Comment: The order is not the same each time. Also, I don't think this would work for me, as sometimes y is longer than x.

Comment: `x = [[292, 2349]], y = [[2922, 349]]` are considered equal here... using `join` is dirty.

Comment: @Emissary how are they equal exactly?

Comment: Joining everything cause a type-losing because everything becomes string.

Comment: They're not - that's the point - but your algorithm will assume they are because the inner arrays when joined both evaluate to `"2922349"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.forEach()`, `Array.prototype.every()`, `Array.prototype.map()`, `Array.prototype.indexOf()`, `JSON.stringify()`, `JSON.parse()`

```
var z = [];
y.forEach(function(val, key) {
  var curr = JSON.stringify(val);
  var match = x.every(function(v, k) {
    return JSON.stringify(v) !== curr
  });
  if (match && z.indexOf(curr) == -1) z.push(curr)
});

z = z.map(JSON.parse);
```

```js
var x = [
  [292, "2349", "902103", "9"],
  [3289, "93829", "092", "920238"]
];
var y = [
  [292, "2349", "902103", "9"],
  [322, "93829", "092", "920238"],
  [924, "9320", "8932", "4329"]
];

var z = [];
y.forEach(function(val, key) {
  var curr = JSON.stringify(val);
  var match = x.every(function(v, k) {
    return JSON.stringify(v) !== curr
  });
  if (match && z.indexOf(curr) == -1) z.push(curr)
});

z = z.map(JSON.parse);

console.log(z);

document.querySelector("pre").textContent = JSON.stringify(z, null, 2)
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have got 2 arrays:

```
var x = [[292,"2349","902103","9"],[3289,"93829","092","920238"]];
var y = [[292,"2349","902103","9"],[322,"93829","092","920238"],[924,"9320","8932","4329"]];
```

To create the Z array, you need the following function:

```
function createZ(){
  var i,j,k=0,z=[],p=x;
  for(j=0;j<y.length;j++){
    for(i=0;i<p.length;i++){
      if(y[j][0]===p[i][0] && y[j][1]===p[i][1] && y[j][2]===p[i][2] && y[j][3]===p[i][3]){
        p.splice(i,1); break;
      } else {
        z[k++]=y[j]; console.log((y[j][0]===p[i][0])+" "+i+","+j);
      }
    }
  }
  return z;
}
```

Note that the createZ() also prints out the i,j of corresponding entry to the console.